# group by and filter data management using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

Take a simple dataset

```
a <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
b <- c(1,2,2,1,2,2,2,2)
c <- c(1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3)
d <- data.frame(a,b,c)
```

now I want to filter my data, so that we `group_by(c)` and then remove all data where no `b=1`occurs.

Thus the results (`e`) should look like `d` but without the two bottom rows

I have tried using

```
e <- d %>%
  group_by(c) %>%
  filter(n(b)>1)
```

The output should contain the data in green below and remove the data in red

[image]

Comment: `e <- d %>% group_by(c) %>% filter( !b == 1)`

Comment: `!b == 1` is equal to `b != 1` which is perhaps a bit more readable?

Comment: not exactly, so for i want to remove each unique ´c´ row where each ´c´ identity does not have a ´b==1´

Comment: i updated the question to make it more understandable

Comment: this doesn't work either `e <- d %>% group_by(c) %>% filter( b == 1 & b == 2 )`

Comment: Not sure why no one said this before, but the function you're looking for is `n_distinct`, like `d %>% group_by(c) %>% filter(n_distinct(b)>1)`

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Try

```
d %>% 
  group_by(c) %>% 
  filter(any(b == 1))
```

Which gives:

```
#Source: local data frame [6 x 3]
#Groups: c
#
#  a b c
#1 1 1 1
#2 2 2 1
#3 3 2 1
#4 4 1 2
#5 5 2 2
#6 6 2 2
```

Comment: Great. Thanks, what is the ´any´ function. it is not documented in http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/dplyr/dplyr.pdf

Comment: @lukeg This is not part of the `dplyr` package. `any()` is in base R. From `?any`: *Given a set of logical vectors, is at least one of the values true?*

Comment: I had a different but related problem, and solved using `all()` *Given a set of logical vectors, are all of the values true*

Answer (score 0):

You can try

```
df <- d %>% mutate(test = ifelse((b != 1) == T, 0, 1)) %>% group_by(c) %>% 
            mutate(test = sum(test)) %>% filter(test != 0) %>% select(-test)
```

which yields

```
#  a b c
#1 1 1 1
#2 2 2 1
#3 3 2 1
#4 4 1 2
#5 5 2 2
#6 6 2 2
```

Comment: That seems overly convoluted. Why don't you chain all your operations ? Why do you create some variables using `mutate()` and some using `$` ? Why do you end with `ungroup()` ?